# Assign value to custom field on dialog panel (Allocation)

Tags: acumatica

I had added a custome field "UsrWgtIndex" on Allocation panel in Purchase Receipts. And its value is the sum of the other custom field "UsrWgtPerUnit".

[image]

But strange thing happened. The value of UsrWgtIndex keeps the same when I open diffrent allocation panel. It is always the value of first row of transations.

[image]

My code is below, and I'm really confused about this. In logic, the code will sum each row of transations, and assign each row of the "UsrWgtIndex". But it's always the value of the first row.

Anyone can help on this? Thanks a lot!

```
namespace PX.Objects.PO {
  public class POReceiptEntry_Extension: PXGraphExtension < POReceiptEntry > {
    #region Event Handlers
    decimal totalCgt = 0 M,
    tempTotal = 0 M;

    protected void POReceiptLine_RowSelected(PXCache cache, PXRowSelectedEventArgs e) {
      POReceiptLine poRLine = (POReceiptLine) e.Row;

      if (poRLine != null) {
        totalCgt = 0 M;
        foreach(POReceiptLineSplit line in Base.splits.Select()) {
          POReceiptLineSplitExt poReceiptLineSplitExt = line.GetExtension < POReceiptLineSplitExt > ();
          var recentQty = poReceiptLineSplitExt.UsrWgtPerUnit;
          var temp = Convert.ToDecimal(recentQty);
          totalCgt = totalCgt + temp;
        };
        var cgt = Convert.ToDecimal(totalCgt);
        if (totalCgt != null) {
          cache.SetValue < POReceiptLineExt.usrTotalWgt > (poRLine, cgt);

          //This line is setting the value of usrWgtIndex
          cache.SetValue < POReceiptLineExt.usrWgtIndex > (poRLine, cgt);
        };
      }
    }
  }
}
```

More detail update:

1. The customer field “usrWgtIndex” belongs to the data class “POReceiptLine”. But I make its control on the Allocations Panel.
2. I had made a test: set value to the field “UnassignedQty” on allocations panel with the same value I give to “usrWgtIndex”. It works correctly. Or  I changed the other field in POReceiptLine data class with same value in the same time, It works fine again.
   3.It seems that if I change a custom field on allocations panel, this strange thing would happen…

More Detail Update2:

I didn't add the "UsrWgtIndex" on the DAC LotSerOptions. I added it on the POReceiptLine. Because when I add the custom field on LotSerOptions, I can't assign its value with setValueEXT methord, it seems there is no DAC named "LotSerOptionsExt".
So I just put "UsrWgtIndex" on DAC POReceiptLine, and assign its value with

```
cache.SetValue<POReceiptLineExt.usrWgtIndex>(poRLine, cgt);
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The 'splits' DataView depends on 'Current' POReceiptLine:

```
PXSelect<POReceiptLineSplit, Where<POReceiptLineSplit.receiptNbr, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.receiptNbr>>,
                                And<POReceiptLineSplit.lineNbr, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.lineNbr>>,
                                And<Where<POLineType.goodsForInventory, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.lineType>>,
                                    Or<POLineType.goodsForSalesOrder, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.lineType>>,
                                    Or<POLineType.goodsForDropShip, Equal<Current<POReceiptLine.lineType>>>>>>>>> splits;
```

The issue is that 'Current' POReceiptLine doesn't change when user clicks (select) another POReceiptLine in 'transactions' grid. Setting the grid 'SyncPosition' to true in your customization project should ensure 'Current' value is properly set when users change record selection in the grid:
[image]

Comment: Hey, dude. Thx for replying. But it doesn't work. Maybe I missed some detail, please check the "more detail update" above.

Comment: Check the value of Base.transactions.Current in POReceiptLine_RowSelected to make sure it match the line selected by user. Use Edit ASPX to make sure SyncPosition in transactions grid is set.

Comment: Also RowSelected will be called for all lines. I would think you need a condition to compute your custom field only for the current line, not all line.

Comment: Base.transactions.Current and ASPX are fine. The most strange is that if I change a exist field or custom field control on POReceiptLine, this wouldn't happen. Split is always belongs to the poreceiptLine I choose.

Comment: Looking in Acumatica base product, the DAC used in the form dataview (LSPOReceiptLine_lotseropts) of the Allocation popup is LotSerOptions. I would expect your custom field to be in that DAC but based on your screenshot it seems you have substantially modified the form section of Allocation popup, the error could be there too. If you redefined the form to use another DAC you also need to make sure Current are properly set there.

Comment: Thx for your patience. But I didn't add the custom field in that form. I created a new one and change its datamember to "transations". Please check the "More Detail Update2" above.

Comment: I think this could very well be the problem. On screens where we have the same data in form and grid we don't share the DataView, we create a new dataview. The pattern is usually "document" and "currentDocument" dataview.

Comment: could you please be more specific about this? You mean create a new data view including the "UsrWgtIndex" and use it as datamember of the new form in Allocations Panel?

Comment: Yes create a new dataview for the form section of allocate. You should avoid binding the same dataview to multiple container control (form, grid, tree view) because it creates problem with Current record.

Comment: OK, I will try it. Thx very much!

Comment: The pattern we use for those Current dataview is this:

Comment: PXSelect<DAC, Where<DAC.Key, Equal<Current<DAC.Key>>>> CurrentDAC

Comment: If DAC has many key, you need to add them all in the Where clause.